# Is there some method to identify the boost version(s) used to create a certain binary?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, g++, x86-64

I was hoping for some method to use something like

```
ident binary
```

or

```
strings - binary
```

in order to identify which boost version(s) was(were) used.

The motivation is to debug some crash after updating the boost version. I suspect that accidentally multiple different boost versions were used.

I already tried

- ldd binary
- /proc/PID/maps
- nm binary
- strings binary
- ident binary

Comment: What does `ldd` say? Are there any boost binaries?

Comment: @n.m.: Even if your binary was dynamically linked against `/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.81.0` or something, that wouldn't tell you whether or not the binary itself contained template functions from a different Boost version that maybe wasn't ABI-compatible.  That's the concern here, I think, that some object files were built with old Boost, some rebuilt with new Boost, and then when linked together into an executable you get breakage.

Comment: @PeterCordes "that wouldn't tell you whether or not the binary itself contained template functions from a different Boost version" — you simply assume it does.

Comment: So... your answer to the OP's question is "assume yes"?  A rebuild will link against the currently-installed `.so` version, seeing a binary with `ldd` doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: @PeterCordes if there's nothing in the ldd output, then the theory about boost upgrade is probably false.

Comment: @n.m.: IDK why you'd conclude that.  If class layouts in headers have changed, old `.o` files compiled with old `.hpp` files linked with new `.o` files from compiling with new `.hpp` files will contain machine code that disagrees about struct layouts, and/or semantics or invariants to maintain.  Of course, the easy fix for that is a `make clean` or equivalent (full rebuild), since it's normal that the build system wouldn't be checking `#include <>` files for changes when considering dependencies for rebuilds.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm assuming the program wasn't rebuilt at all. A correct rebuild would rebuild everything that depends on boost. If it was rebuilt incorrectly for some reason, then well, there's a problem with the build script probably.